# Unable to activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to install bcrypt to handle passwords.

I ran `gem install bcrypt-ruby` and got:

```
....Successfully installed bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2
```

I added `gem "bcrypt-ruby", "~> 3.1.2"` and ran `bundle install`, and restarted the server which ran the program but I got the error:

```
get Gem::LoadError in UsersController#new 
can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.


format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
**has_secure_password** <---Error
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: is it able to change `~> 3.0.0` to `~> 3.0`

Comment: you need to see in **Gemfile.lock** which gem require 3.1.2 version of bcrypt-ruby, and try to downdrade it.

Comment: sorry yes i undestand now :) changed gemfile to 3.0 works now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~> 3.0.0` version conflicts with `~> 3.1.2` one, because comparison takes place `3.0.~` to `3.1.~`, and failed. You shave to change `~> 3.0.0` to `~> 3.0`, in order to compare `3.~` to `3.1`.

If you are unable to do it, you have to see into **Gemfile.lock**, which gem require `3.1.2` version of `bcrypt-ruby` in, and try to downdrade it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the Gemfile line to...

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

and then bundle and that should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle update
```

I would also recommend simply putting `gem "bcrypt-ruby", "3.1.2"` in the Gemfile.