# Ruby on Rails bcrypt-ruby error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt-ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial for Rails 4, and I'm working on the user auth section. He says to add `bcrypt-ruby` to the Gemfile, then `bundle install`.

Here's the line from my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2' // as explained at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-bcrypt_ruby
```

I ran `bundle install` and then `rails console` to test the system. Creating a new user throws the following error:

```
You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Gem::LoadError: can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

The `bundle install` worked fine and didn't throw any errors-- why is this failing here, with an error saying `bcrypt-ruby` is not installed?

EDIT: this appears to be a duplicate of this question: [Unable to activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581971/unable-to-activate-bcrypt-ruby-3-0-0-already-activated-bcrypt-ruby-3-1-2?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741040/cant-activate-bcrypt-ruby-3-0-0-already-activated-bcrypt-ruby-3-1-1-make)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `bcrypt-ruby` version `3.0.0`

Change the version in your Gemfile

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```